# Some MBP keys won't work after logging in

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a 13 inch mid 2012 MBP, I'm having problems with some of my keys, some of my keys don't work such as u I O j k L m, but the wierd thing is that they work perfectly fine during the login screen, but don't work after logging in

Comment: do they work in Safe mode ? Also did you try using the virtual keyboard (on screen)

Comment: If you keep the [u] key pressed, does your cursor move?

Answer (score 1):

Disable mouse keys which is an accessibility function.

Type <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>, and suppress the check mark there:[image: disable mouse keys]